# Filtering queryset with objects

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

Currently I have

```
foreach($this->friends as $friend) {
    $user_ids[] = $friend->id;
}

$posts = Post::whereIn("user_id", $user_ids)->orderBy("date_published", "desc")->paginate(15);
```

Seems okay and works fine, but the creation of the array is a little weird. Is there a way I could filter by the User objects themselves? For example

```
Post::whereIn("user", $this->friends)
```

where `$this->friends` would be

```
public function friends() {
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\User", "friends_users", "user_id", "friend_id");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->friends` is a `Collection` object which has a `lists` method which creates an array from a column, or an associative array from 2 columns.  Here's how you would use it.

```
$posts = Post::whereIn("user_id", $this->friends->lists('id'))->orderBy("date_published", "desc")->paginate(15);
```